# laravel with multiple model relation on pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a State, County, salesTeam, and user models.

SalesTeam.php

```
public function state(){
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
    }
public function manager(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'manager_id');
    }
```

State.php

```
public function counties(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\County')->orderBy('county');
}
```

County.php

What I am trying to achieve is that there might be some cases where there is a submanager assigned to a salesTeam but only to a specific county. I created a table like this (I believe I need it, correct me if I don't):

```
Schema::create('sub_managers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('salesteam_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('state_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('submanager_id');                                                  
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

how do I interact with this type of relationship? I thought I needed the table cause it made sense, but now I don't know how to relate to it do I have to make the model too? and if so how do I relate a county to a submanager to take into account the salesteam it is assigned to?

Comment: I would suggest a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between SalesTeam and User. Use [columns in the pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns) to represent if it's regular manager or sub-manager, and also for an applicable county ID.

Comment: but do i need the extra model or just the table?

Comment: @miken32also, how do i take into account the county?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked. No model, just a pivot table with additional columns.